# How to add command line properties with gradle bootRun?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

[24.3 Application Property Files](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.4.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files) uses the following command to add an application property `spring.config.name`:

> $ java -jar myproject.jar --spring.config.name=myproject

How can I do this with `gradle bootRun`?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

BootRun task extends JavaExec task: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.4.RELEASE/gradle-plugin/api/org/springframework/boot/gradle/tasks/run/BootRun.html

Since Gradle 4.9, the command line arguments can be passed with --args. For example, if you want to launch the application with command line arguments foo --bar, you can use:

```
gradle bootRun --args='--spring.config.name=myproject'
```

Comment: `gradle bootRun --args '--spring.config.name=myproject'` does not work for me. But `gradle bootRun --args='--spring.config.name=myproject'` works for me. I am running Grdle 4.9 on macOS 10.13.6. @jreznot, could please use `gradle bootRun --args='--spring.config.name=myproject'` in your answer? So I can accept your answer.

Comment: Interestingly, when running Gradle 5.5 from IntelliJ IDEA on WIndows, the version with `=` didn't work for me, but the `gradle bootRun --args 'myarg'` did.

Comment: If you want to pass multiple arguments, simply separate them with a space: `gradle bootRun --args='--spring.config.name=myproject --another.argument=foo'`